# Galois group on rational functions field and $n$ variables

Tags: galois-theory

Suppose $G$ ist the Galois group of $L|K$ which permutes the roots $\alpha_i$.
With the $n$ variables $t_1,\dots,t_n$ we have the fields of rational functions $K(t_1,\dots,t_n)$ and $L(t_1,\dots,t_n)$.
How can I show that $L(t_1,\dots,t_n)^G = K(t_1,\dots,t_n)$?

Comment: Presumably $G$ acts on the coefficients without moving the variables? If so, look at an $F\in L(X)$ that happens to be fixed under the action of $G$. What does that mean, for the coefficients of the numerator and denominator of $F$?